# What does the pycharm error code ( -1073741571) mean?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run my code on a small test graph my code works but when I give it a bigger file my code fails to read it and returns the error code -1073741571. Does anyone know what causes this?

I have searched the internet and cannot find any reference to the code -1073741571

```py
def load_graph():
    graphfwd = []
    graphrev = []
    explored = []
    h = 0
    with open('SCC.txt', 'r') as graphInput:
        lines = graphInput.readlines()
        maxime = 0
        for line in lines:
            ints = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            for i in ints:
                if i > maxime:
                    maxime = i
        graphfwd = [[] for x in range(maxime + 1)]
        graphrev = [[] for x in range(maxime + 1)]

        for line in lines:
            ints = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            graphfwd[ints[0]].append(ints[1])
            graphrev[ints[1]].append(ints[0])

    return graphfwd, graphrev, maxime
```

Comment: Could you also show what's in your `SCC.txt`?

Comment: The Error code is actually -1073741571

Comment: SCC.txt is a file with the vertices of the graph represented by "node node\n"

Comment: That error code is perhaps better expressed as 0xC00000FD, which is a stack overflow on Windows.  I see no way it could be produced by the code you posted, it's more likely to be coming from some recursive algorithm that works with the graph that you loaded.

Comment: please share error image

Comment: I ran my code through idle and got a stack overflow error.  Pycharm did give me the code 0xC000FD. The rest my code is a recursive SCC algorithem so this makes since now.